# plone change in code not visible in development site 

Tags: python-2.7, plone, zope

I am very new to plone. I have a project folder in eclipse. I have imported it from the cvs project. I have zope as server and I start zope with `./bin/instance restart`. When I make changes in my folder, I cannot see the changes in the development website. I can't seem to find what is happening. I even restarted zope after making changes in python. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: bin/buildout runs buildout, a make-like system for configuring your environment. It does things like take values from buildout.cfg and puts them in parts/instance/etc/zope.conf. You probably want to run bin/instance instead to run Zope.

Comment: yes, it was not buildout but restart!

Comment: what is your folder? where is it placed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you start your Zope server with `bin/instance fg`, most likely the name of the script if you used the Plone universal installer buildout.

To see changes in python code you'll either need to restart the server (CTRL-C then start again) or use something like [`plone.reload`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.reload) to request a reload of changed code.

When starting your server with the `fg` command, it is automatically running in debug mode and any templates, resources and skin items are reloaded automatically. Start the server with `console` or `start` and it'll run in production mode and templates and such are loaded from disk only once.

See the [Plone.org documentation on buildout](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/managing-projects-with-buildout/creating-a-buildout-for-your-project) for more information.

The `bin/instance` command has a built-in help command, try:

```
bin/instance help
```

for a list of supported commands or run:

```
bin/instance help console
```

to get help on a specific command; the above example will print the help on the `console` command.

Comment: There are still no changes displayed. When I do `bin/instance fg`, it tells something like "zope is ready". However, when I reload the page, I don't see any changes. For instance, I had the text field with label "abc" before, now I want to change it into "abcd". So, what I did was just stopped the instance, and started it again with `bin/instance fg`. Do I need to do anything more?

Comment: @SadikshaGautam: Restart the server or use plone.reload (still needs an explicit page visit, see it's manual).